# Can't get SQL code working on Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

With the exception of a little HTML/Javascript, I've always used C++ on Visual Studio C++ 2010. I have an internship next week that will involve the use of SQL and .Net.  I'm currently reading a book on SQL and it instructs us to go to its website to download code so that we can practice. The website is here: http://forta.com/books/0672336073/ I downloaded the one labeled "Microsoft SQL Server" which is basically two .sql files. One creates a simple database and the other one populates it.

However, for the life of me I cant figure out how to do it on Visual Studio 2010 or 2013 (I downloaded the full version of 2010).  If anyone knows how to get these file to run on either VS version I would be very happy. I'm used to just hitting the green arrow button in Visual Studio C++ 2010, which I believe is execute. Obviously it isnt working for my sql code.

On VS 2013 I created a new "SQL Server Database Project". I then added two new "Application Role" items for the two .sql files. Now after clicking the "SQL" tab and "Execute" I get error messages about duplicate objects/keys, which I assume means the database is already created...but how do I view it? At one instance I mustve hit the right combination of buttons because I was able to view my database in a table format.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you have sql server managment studio installed?

Comment: I dont. Whats the difference between that and VS? They seem like they would be similar, being Microsoft products. I was using VS since the company I will be working for suggested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio go to view and select sql server, (see image) then click the + symbol and connect to the server installed on your machine (if its not yet listed)

[image]

Comment: I did what you said and added "(localdb)\Projects"...what next? As I said it appears the database is created. Heres an error: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Vendors'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Vendors'. The duplicate key value is (BRS01     )." Im just not sure how to view it or run more commands on it...

Comment: Make a right click on (localdb)\Projects and select New Query.

Comment: Ok did that. I put in the code to make the tables and it ran. Of course running it again causes it to say the objects already exist.  Should I make another new query and put in my populate .sql code? I can also now see under localdb\Project is the Databases folder with the databases Ive attempted to make.

Comment: All the objects are there. you're done.. no need to execute again.

Comment: I also ran the populate code and it worked. But how do I view the table? And how do I run new code, such as "SELECT * FROM". Do I make a new .sql file?